# How to multiply all value and of key in hashmap in java

Tags: java, hashmap

I m looking for a way to multiply all values and all keys in hashmap in java.

I m in this situation, I have this hashmap that contains these values.

`{1:3, 2:2}`

I would like to multiply all keys (in this case 1*2)
in a dynamic way and put in a variable and after I would like to multiply all values and put in another variable.

How Can I do this in java ?

Comment: So you want to put the result into a *different* `Map` (i.e. not modify the existing one in-place). Right? Could you also post the expected resulting map, just to be clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stream through keys/values and use `reduce` method to multiply keys/values

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>(); // the same logic will work for Long type, you need to change other variable types

final Integer multipliedKeysValue = map.keySet().stream().reduce(1, (a, b) -> a * b);
final Integer multipliedValuesValue = map.values().stream().reduce(1, (a, b) -> a * b);
```

---

Read more here:

- [Java stream reduction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/reduction.html)

Comment: "the same logic will work for Long type, just you need to change other variable types" Really?

Comment: Yes why not? You just need to create `Map<Long, Long>`, `Long multipliedKeysValue` variable (the same for 'values') and `1L` in `reduce` - isn't it right?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using the loop (assuming your map is in `map` variable):

```
long keysProduct = 1;
long valuesProduct = 1;

for (var entry : map.entrySet()) {
    keysProduct *= entry.getKey();
    valuesProduct *= entry.getValue();
}
```

`map.entrySet()` will return key-value pairs from the map so you iterate over them and store the product of keys and values in corresponding variables.

**NB:** Please note that `var` is available since Java 10, if you use Java 9 or older consider replacing it with `Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>`!